# Move named instance to another server

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

To be honest I'm not a DBA expert. I get asked by one of my clients in terms of moving a SQL Server development instance that is stored in the production server (source) to another server (destination)

The source server has two volumes E and F:

- Volum E stores Databases (E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SPDEV\MSSQL\DATA)
- Volum F stores Logs (F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SPDEV\MSSQL\Data)

I have backed one database (Backup_Test.bak) for testing purpose in the source server and restored to the destination by using the following T-SQL via SQL Server Management Studio in the destination:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Backup_Test
FROM DISK = 'C:\SQLBackup\Backup_Tesk.bak' \\\Stored in the destination
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'Backup_Test' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SPDEV\MSSQL\DATA\Backup_Test.mdf',
MOVE 'Backup_Test_log' TO 'F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SPDEV\MSSQL\Data\Backup_Test_log.ldf'
```

After executing, I get the error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near 'MOVE'.

In the destination, someone installed SQL Server and locate all things stored in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER.

I'm suspecting that different location on both the source (E & F) and destination (only C) causes my issue. If so, do I have to re-install SQL Server on the destination?

The version on the source is SQL Server 2008 and on the destination is /R2. The named instance on the source is SQLSP1\SPDEV and on the destination is SQLSP2. Do I have to create an alias SQLSP2\SPDEV?

Many thanks for your help. I really appreciate.

Regards,
-T.s

Answer (score 2):

You are not moving instances, you are copying databases via backup restore. All you need is to get the syntax right, as per [`RESTORE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) spec:

```
<general_WITH_options> [ ,...n ]::= 
--Restore Operation Options
   MOVE 'logical_file_name_in_backup' TO 'operating_system_file_name' 
          [ ,...n ]
```

Each WITH option is separated from the preceding with a comma. What you're missing is the **,** *and* you need to move the files into the destination location:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Backup_Test
FROM DISK = 'C:\SQLBackup\Backup_Tesk.bak' \\\Stored in the destination
WITH REPLACE
 , MOVE 'Backup_Test' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\Backup_Test.mdf',
 , MOVE 'Backup_Test_log' TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\Backup_Test_log.ldf'
```

Judging from your folder names (`MSSQL10` vs. `MSSQL10_50`) your source server is SQL Server 2008 (**not R2**) and only the destination is SQL Server 2008 R2. Which means that the copy will upgrade the database and the database will never be possible to copy/restore on the original non-R2 instance.

Comment: Thanks. I've missed a comma after REPLACE. I have a further question. On the destionation, C:\SQL_Data stores all databases and C:\SQL_Logs stores all Logs. On the source, as you see in my question, E:\path\Data stores all databases and F:\path\Data\ stores all logs. Do I have to re-structure drives on the destination? Or my script above can be probably used in my case. Many thanks for help.

Comment: I've changed the path:

Move 'Backup_Test' TO 'C:\SQL_DATA\Backup_Test.mdf'
Move 'Backup_Test_log' TO 'C:\SQL_Logs\Backup_Test_log.ldf'

The script is succesfully executed without any error message but I don't know if it's done.

Comment: if it executed w/o errors and finished it means is done. You should now have a database called `Backup_Test` on the destination which is a copy of the original.

Answer (score 1):

```
RESTORE DATABASE Backup_Test
FROM DISK = 'C:\SQLBackup\Backup_Tesk.bak' \\\Stored in the destination
WITH REPLACE,
MOVE 'Backup_Test' TO 'E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SPDEV\MSSQL\DATA\Backup_Test.mdf',
MOVE 'Backup_Test_log' TO 'F:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SPDEV\MSSQL\Data\Backup_Test_log.ldf'
```

Only you need add comma after REPLACE key